# Как вызвать константу из heredoc?

Tags: php, const

Имеется такой PHP код:

```
echo <<<TEST
 Какой то текст, какая то {$value}. 
 Но как вызвать константу {CONST}
TEST;
```

Внутри heredoc очень нужно обратиться к константе. Как это сделать. Так как в примере это не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str= <<<TEST
      Какой то текст, какая то {$value}. Но как вызвать константу %s
TEST;

echo sprintf($str, CONST);
```

Comment: Не работает так. Пишет - Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments i

Comment: А сама константа как объявлена?

Comment: Через define...

Comment: Вы пишите на чистом php, или это cms/framework? И можете изменить имя константы и попробовать ещё раз по моему примеру.

Comment: На чистом php и у меня другое имя константы

Comment: Благодарю за минус в попытке помочь вам разобраться). Вот ссылка на рабочий код по вашему вопросу: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/746c5bf4d4e75f3e0cfb503ffc0cd1217795b382

Comment: А я Вам не ставил минус. (

Comment: Тогда пардон) В любом случае проблема в чём-то другом.

Comment: Мистика) У мну работает: http://prntscr.com/n4v1vg

Comment: Спасибо. Подумаю еще. Этот вариант все таки работает. Но почему то  в моем случае не так.